# Inheritance with Stapes.js

Tags: javascript, inheritance, stapes.js

I'm trying to make a parent/child link with the JS framework [Stapes.js](http://hay.github.com/stapes/#m-subclass).

Here is my code:

```
var Parent = Stapes.subclass({
    constructor: function () {
        this.name = 'syl';
    }
});

var Child = Parent.subclass({
    constructor: function (value) {
        this.value = value;

        console.log(this.name); // undefined
    }
});

var child = new Child('a value');
```

Fiddle [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/n5kwL/).

How to access to the parent's name property from the child class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved, see [details](https://github.com/hay/stapes/issues/37#issuecomment-15392595).

Answer (score 5):

For those that are to lazy to click on the link, here's the full answer i gave on Github:

Child classes do not automatically run the constructor of their parent. You need to run it manually. You could either do this:

```
var Child = Parent.subclass({
    constructor : function() {
        Parent.prototype.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
    }
});
```

or this:

```
var Child = Parent.subclass({
    constructor : function() {
        Child.parent.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
    } 
});
```

In both cases, doing a

```
var child = new Child();
alert(child.name);
```

Will give an alertbox with 'syl'